# How to enable xmlwriter after PHP having been compiled?

Tags: php, xmlwriter

I've got a message that `ext/xmlwriter` is missing while trying to set up phpMyFAQ on my system of Fedora 15. I looked it up on the PHP manual and got this:

> This extension is enabled by default. It may be disabled by using the following option at compile time: **--disable-xmlwriter**

I used yum to install PHP on my computer and consider recompiling PHP quite an unpleasant work. Can I just enable it by editing something, like `php.ini`? Or any other ways to accomplish this task without recompiling PHP? And how?

Comment: Using `phpinfo()` or `php -i` on the commandline you should be able to see what the compile time options were for your PHP build. Can you see if there's any mention of `xmlwriter` there?

Comment: Yes. And `--disable-xmlwriter` is indeed in the configure command.

Comment: It can probably be built (and thus loaded via php.ini) as separate .so module. Else (strongly discouraged) eventually be installed via [`pecl install xmlwriter`](http://pecl.php.net/package/xmlwriter).

Comment: I just noticed the PHP manual saying that `This extension has no configuration directives defined in php.ini.` Does this mean that there's no possibility to enable it by `php.ini`?

Comment: Try `yum install php-xmlwriter` or `yum install php-xml`.

Comment: I'd seen php-xml in yum before, but didn't think it would work... until now. `yum install php-xml` and editing `php.ini` make this really work!

Answer (score 30):

on Ubuntu
as root

`apt install php-xmlwriter`

worked for me

else

```
sudo apt install php-xmlwriter
```

Answer (score 22):

In the context of modern PHP, since PHP 7 works the following library to solve this problem - `php7.3-xml` as an example for PHP 7.3. It also works for another version; change only for your PHP version.

Install for Ubuntu system is like: `sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml`

If you will install without the version knowledge, install it via `sudo apt-get install php-xml`.

Comment: This is the right answer, though invalid because versions change. Use `sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Comment: For CentOS 7.8: `sudo yum install php-xml`

Answer (score 18):

Running the following as recommended by netcoder worked for me

yum install php-xmlwriter

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem while moving to new server:

1) Check that **libxml** installed:

```
php -i | grep "xml"
```

Result example:

```
1   /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
2   /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
3   xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
4   xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
5   libxml
6   mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|applicatio...
7   Simplexml support => enabled
8   xml
9   libxml2 Version => 2.7.6
10  xmlwriter
```

Lines 5, 9 & 10 told us that all ok.

2) If not installed (example for CentOS):

```
yum install libxml2
```

and restart server:

```
/etc/apache2 restart
```

or php-fpm:

```
/etc/php-fpm restart
```

maybe will useful next variants:

```
yum install php-xmlwriter
yum install php-xml
```

**For php from sources** in latest versions `xmlwriter` enabled by default, but you can check, that key `--disable-xmlwriter` not set.


**3) Last step** - file:

```
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini
```

Needing to be look like:

```
; Enable xmlwriter extension module
extension=xmlwriter.so
```

I think latest string - it's main decition for the problem.